# Macro to transpose based on nearby column number

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

This screenshot has details on what is needed.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I need a macro that can perform the following in Excel:

- Use column F numbers (Line Count), to place in the values from column E (Part Text) to column G, H, I, J, K and L “Description” field". (For Example : E2 to be placed in G2 (Description 1), E3 to be placed in H2 (Description 2), E4 to be placed in I2 (Description 3)  and E5 to be placed in J2 (Description 4). [see screenshot]

NOTE : 1. I wanted only to use, the column  F “Line Number”,which has the value "1", (The G column next to value 1) that’s where the description writing should start on all the rows flowingly for all unique Part Numbers like (210014, 232260). For example (The description writing will start on lines G2, G6 and G10 respectively).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with formulas in columns g,H,I,J,K,L etc.
You may be able to simplify this for your needs once you see how this is working.
You could only have the formulas in the rows where LineCount is 1 or use the formulas such as this in each of these **cell addresses** and drag down

**G2**   =IF(F2<>1,"",E2)

**H2**   =IF(F2<>1,"",IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+1)=0,"",INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+1)))

**I2**   =IF(F2<>1,"",IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+2)=0,"",INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+2)))

**J2**   =IF(F2<>1,"",IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+3)=0,"",INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+3)))

**K2**   =IF(F2<>1,"",IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+4)=0,"",INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+4)))

**L2**   =IF(F2<>1,"",IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+5)=0,"",INDIRECT("E"&ROW()+5)))

You can expand this depending upon the amount of expected rows you need fairly easily and this is a quick solution that might be written even better if you experiment

If you absolutely need a macro you can implement the same ideas within it